# How are the structure fields getting populated?

Tags: c, data-structures, structure

When I execute the following C program, the output is `i`.

```
struct student {
    char a[5];
};
int main() {
    struct student s[] = { "hi","hey" };
    printf("%c", s[0].a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to understand what is the function of the command `struct student s[] = { "hi","hey" };`
Any possible justification will be highly helpful.

Comment: Which language C **OR** C++?  In C++ the `struct` is not required when creating an instance of the `struct` or in parameter declarations.

Comment: It is C language. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition

```
struct student s[] = { "hi","hey" };
```

is equivalent to

```
struct student s[2] = { { "hi" }, { "hey" } };
```

So `s[0]` is the first element of the array `s`. And `s[0].a[1]` will be the second character of `s[0].a`.